# JQuery draggable item disappears in droppable on droppable.append(draggable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Using JQuery draggable/droppables to allow me to drag divs from one container to another and have them inserted as children into the container. I can see the move in HTML but on the screen the div disappears when i release the draggable into the target.

http://jsfiddle.net/laurencefass/tqqLxquL/2/

```
    <div id="left" class="droppable">
    <div class="draggable">1</div>
    <div class="draggable">2</div>
    <div class="draggable">3</div>
    <div class="draggable">4</div>
</div>
<div id="right" class="droppable">drag blocks in here</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.draggable').draggable();

$(init);

function init() {
  $('.draggable').draggable();
  $('.droppable').droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
  });
}
```

css

```
.draggable {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:gray;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:100;
    display:block;
}
.droppable {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exemple of what I understood you want to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/tqqLxquL/5/

The dragged element have a left property when dropped, you have to override it.

```
    function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
       console.log($(ui.draggable[0]));
       var $draggable = $(ui.draggable[0]);  
       $draggable.appendTo(this);
         $draggable.css({
            left: 0
         })
    }
```